# Launch a "shortcut" in Tasker?

Tags: tasker

Can Tasker launch an app's shortcut as an action? I can't find "Shortcuts" as an option in the "Select Action Category"-dialog when creating a new task. This works without problems in Locale.

Comment: What do you mean by "launch an app's shortcut"? Do you mean, "can Tasker launch/start an app?"

Comment: Apps can declare "shortcuts" (e.g. the SMS-app can declare a shortcut to its "Compose new text"-screen). The available shortcuts can be viewed if you long-press a free area of your homescreen and select "Shortcut" instead of "Widget". The "Locale" app can start these shortcuts (instead of the app), I'm asking if the Tasker-app can do the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strangely, this does not appear to be possible in Tasker, by default. However, I see there is the [AutoShortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoshortcut&hl=en) app on Google Play which is meant to allow it. Interestingly, Tasker itself will tell you about [AutoShortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoshortcut&hl=en) (complete with a link to Google Play) if you press the magnifying glass icon when attempting to add a plugin action to a task (I'll update this answer with screen shots when I get around to it).

Theoretically, it should also be possible using the `Send Intent` action, but that seems way more complicated than should be necessary for such a simple task. If [AutoShortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoshortcut&hl=en) doesn't work for you, let me know, and I can try to figure out what the Intent settings should be.

Comment: Thanks, Trebor! Yeah, I found it weird, too, especially since Tasker has a gazillion of "target" options, including shortcuts should be a pretty intuitive/basic choice. Thank you for the "AutoShortcut"-suggestion, this does indeed look very helpful. I'm developing an app that I want to integrate with Tasker, and it already has a number of shortcuts, so I didn't want to develop a standalone Tasker-plugin on top. I'll direct my users to the AutoShortcut-app.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin) lets you launch shortcuts from Tasker in the same way as [AutoShortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoshortcut&hl=en) but without all the annoying ads and nags. So I prefer using that method.

But neither method is really that great, I have a bunch of shortcuts they can't seem to launch.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to switch to Automagic. What you're asking is a simple matter of selecting the "class" option in "Launch App." It gives you a complete list of available "shortcuts" to launch. Automagic has 90% of the functionality of Tasker, and requires fewer plugins. However, it will also use all the plugins Tasker can use.
Also, the interface is a hundred times easier to learn.

Answer (score 0):

LS

In tasker there is a field data. When starting Chrome, one can fill in a url is this field and Chrom then starts with this url. I asume that othe apps will also react in a simular way.

Regards, Martin